# Access denied when updating config file in ProgramData directory. How do I fix this?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, permissions, installation

I can't seem to update my configuration file in c:\ProgramData\appname\config.ini. I keep getting an access denied error. Seems the ini code fails to be able to delete the existing .ini file when trying to update it with the new file. Funny thing is that I have other programs I've written that share the same code but don't have this problem. This is troubling.

Comparing my working program with this non working program, I noticed that when I click on the security tab for the ini file, I see that my user name [Scott] is not listed under "Group or Usernames" like in the working program's ini file. Also, the non working one has a shield next to Delete and Rename (when right click on filename) while the working one does not have this. How can I set the permissions? The setup file for both projects is identical and when I create the folder and copy the program file in Isso Setup, no permissions are set (read only flag is not set, hidden is not set, and System is not set).

Why am I getting this and how come my other program install and works fine? Installer runs as administrator and does the access permission prompting. What do I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

This is because your program was not run as an administrator. You have to either run your program as an administrator or move your .ini file and any other files you wish to update during the duration of the program to a location like C:\Users\\AppData\Local\. Note that for the latter option you will have to update your program likewise.
To run your program as an administrator right-click on ur program (or shortcut) and click **Run as Administrator**.